# Django REST how to not apply default permission for get request

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I don't want to apply my `permission_classes` for `get` request. I tried `@permission_classes([AllowAny])` but didn't work.

Here is my my code:

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly & IsAuthorGroup]

    @permission_classes([AllowAny])
    def list(self, request):
        if request.method == "GET":
            blog = Blog.objects.all().order_by("id")
            serializer = BlogSerializer(blog, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I also tried this and getting `local variable 'permission_classes' referenced before assignment` for `post` `put` `patch` and `delete` request

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly & IsAuthorGroup]

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            permission_classes = [
                AllowAny,
            ]

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply pass a permission class like this.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, AllowAny, IsAdminUser
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthenticated ]

    queryset = Blog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    pagination_class = BlogPagination
    lookup_field = 'blog_slug'
```

And you can write your own permission classes to pass it. and user will access this view only if they will have all permissions.

Hope this will help you :)